# How to set path for exporting files from Maya using PySide2 ad Python

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

I'm learning Python while trying to develop helper tools for Maya using Python and PySide. (Quite ambitious but there is no progress without challenges, right)

Basically, I'm writing a tool that would help me export animation as fbx files to a folder I set in any given location on my PC.

I've finished to write the export process. There should be no issue here, I'm stuck with the UI part of it.

[image]

Currently this is how my UI is looking. I want to be able to set the path to the place where I want the script to export the files.
[image]

When I select the path and press "Select Folder", I want the path of the selected folder to display in the text line of the UI. And "Remember" it so that when I press Export FBX animation or Export rig it would use that path and would save files there.

But I have no clue how to do that. Can anyone help the clueless me how to make this happen?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you )

Here is my current code:

`

```
import CreatureAnimBakeProcess
reload(CreatureAnimBakeProcess)
from maya import cmds
import os
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class CreatureAnimBakeUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CreatureAnimBakeUI, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Creature Exporter')
        self.library = CreatureAnimBakeProcess.CreatureExport()
        self.buildUI()


    def buildUI(self):
        print 'building ui'
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        setPathWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        setPathLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(setPathWidget)

        layout.addWidget(setPathWidget)
        self.setPathField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        setPathLayout.addWidget(self.setPathField)
        setBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Set Export Folder')
        setBtn.clicked.connect(self.setPath)
        setPathLayout.addWidget(setBtn)

        #============================================

        btnWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        btnLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(btnWidget)
        layout.addWidget(btnWidget)

        ExportFBXBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Export FBX Animation')
        ExportFBXBtn.clicked.connect(self.exportFbxAnim)
        btnLayout.addWidget(ExportFBXBtn)

        ExportRIGBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Export RIG')
        ExportRIGBtn.clicked.connect(self.exportRIG)
        btnLayout.addWidget(ExportRIGBtn)


        return

    def getDirectory(self):
        directory = os.path.join(cmds.internalVar(userAppDir=True), 'Animation')
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.mkdir(directory)
        return

    def setPath(self):
        directory = self.getDirectory()
        pathName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, directory, "Creature Exporter")
        return

    def exportFbxAnim(self):
        pass

    def exportRIG(self):
        pass




def showUI():
    ui = CreatureAnimBakeUI()
    ui.show()
    return ui
```

`

Comment: Oh? where should I put these parts? In the BuildUI module or in the setPath module?

Comment: I have given the changes below as code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self.setPathField.setText(pathName)` to show the value, you can also assign it to `self.exportPath = pathName` so you can re use it.

I am only showing code snippets where I changed, the remainder of your code needs no changes.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(CreatureAnimBakeUI, self).__init__()

        # have it assigned to None
        self.exportPath = None  # changed here

        self.setWindowTitle("Creature Exporter")
        self.buildUI()
```

```
    def setPath(self):
        directory = self.getDirectory()
        pathName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, directory, "Creature Exporter"
        )
        if pathName:  # changed here
            # "remember the value"
            self.exportPath = pathName
            # show it in the text line of the UI
            self.setPathField.setText(pathName)
        return
```

`self.exportPath` will be `None` initially, once you select a folder it will have that value saved. So this `if` checks if the value is not set and forces the user to set a value, if it is already set that value will be used.

```
    def exportFbxAnim(self):  # changed here
        if self.exportPath is None:
            # call self.setPath if self.exportPath is None
            self.setPath()

        # self.exportPath should have the value you expect

    def exportRIG(self):  # changed here
        if self.exportPath is None:
            # call self.setPath if self.exportPath is None
            self.setPath()

        # self.exportPath should have the value you expect
```